# Help with arithmetic on basic Taylor Series expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

There are two of the steps below that I would seek assistance on the arithmetic.

From the wikipedia article on Taylor series:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

The Maclaurin series for $(1 − x)^{-1}$ is the geometric series

[image]

a) I am not able to complete the arithmetic from the first to second lines : i.e. 
"…so the Taylor series for ${x}^{-1}$ at $a=1$ is…"

b) And also the 2nd to third lines: "By integrating the above Maclaurin series, we find the Maclaurin series for $\log(1-x)$".  Which line did they integrate - it appears they integrated the `Taylor series` not the Maclaurin?

Comment: For the first question, they just shifted the $x$, so instead of being around $0$, it is about $1$. For the second, they integrated *both*. Read carefully.

Comment: @OFRBG  On the first one: there is an alternating -1^n sign. I can't follow where that came into play. I do not understand your comment about they integrated "both".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition from the first to the second line is using the substitution $(1-x) \rightarrow x$, i.e. replacing all ocurrences of $1-x$ with $x$. If the subsititution makes you feel uncomfortable, you can always use the intermediate step of letting $u = 1-x$, getting the second line but with $u$ instead of $x$, and then noting that since we're talking about arbitrary variables that you can replace $u$ with $x$ and get the same result. (Noting that, since the Maclaurin series is the Taylor series around $x = 0$, after the substitution it becomes a series around $x = 1$.)

For the second part, they most definitely integrated the Maclaurin series for $(1-x)^{-1}$ with respect to $x$.

EDIT to expand:

We start with:

$(1-x)^{-1} = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^n + \ldots$

Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ gives:

$\begin{eqnarray}\int (1-x)^{-1} dx & = & \int 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^n + \ldots dx \\
-\log{(1-x)} + C & = & x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{3}x^3 + \ldots + \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1} + \ldots\end{eqnarray}$

which you can verify by differentiating the second line. Substituting $x = 0$ lets us know that $C = 0$, so we then get the identity:

$\log{(1-x)} = -x - \frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{3}x^3 - \ldots$

Then we make the substitution $u = 1 - x$ and we get:

$\begin{eqnarray}\log{u} & = & -(1 - u) - \frac{1}{2}(1 - u)^2 - \frac{1}{3}(1 - u)^3 - \ldots \\
& = & -(-1) \times (u - 1) - \frac{1}{2}(-1)^2 \times (u - 1)^2 - \frac{1}{3}(-1)^3 \times (u - 1)^3 - \ldots \\
& = & (u - 1) - \frac{1}{2}(u - 1)^2 + \frac{1}{3}(u - 1)^3 - \ldots\end{eqnarray}$

Where the last couple of lines were just extracting $(-1)$ from each $(1-u)$. Then all you have to do is swap $u$ back to $x$ and you're done.

Comment: This is helpful. I have added my own answer to bring out clearly a skipped step that tripped me.  I still do not follow the integration step.

Answer (score 0):

This 'answer' is actually just commentary/ building on @conman 's answer.

A step that was elided over in the original presentation from wiki is the use of

1-(1-x) = -1 * (x -1)

They have swapped the order of 1-x to x-1 and pulled out a -1 factor. Then this also explains the alternating (-1)^n  which results in odd powers having negative coefficients and and even powers having positive coefficients.